# Display User info from Meteor.users, and display with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, highcharts

I'm new in Meteor, that's what I'd like to do: I've some users that will answer to different kind of questions: *feels* and *answers* are the answers that I'll store in the mongoDB for each user.
Now this is my HTML:

```
<p>Select a user to see infos, see answers' progress</p>
{{#each allUsers}}

  <div class="patinf">
    <br>
    <h5><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{lastName}} {{firstName}}</h5> 
    <label>
      <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="{{this.id}}" id="show" value="show" required>
      <span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Show answers</span>
    </label> 
    <label>
      <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="{{this.id}}" id="hide" value="hide" checked>
        <span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hide</span
    </label>
  </div>
  {{#if show}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="something" class="control-label">Answers' Progress</label>
      <div id="something">
        <p>Feelings:</p>
        <ul>
          {{#each allFeelings}}
            <li>{{feel}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
        <p>Answers:</p>
        <ul>
          {{#each allAnswers}}
            <li>{{answer}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
        <br>
       </div>
       <div id="something" style=" min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0auto">
         {{> highchartsHelper chartId="feels" chartWidth="100%" charHeight="100%" chartObject=topGenresChart}}
         <br>
         {{> highchartsHelper chartId="answers" chartWidth="100%" charHeight="100%" chartObject=topGenresChart}}
       </div>
     </div>
   {{/if}}
 {{/each}}
```

And this is my js file:

```
Meteor.subscribe('patientInfos');

Template.patients.helpers({
  allAnswers:function(){
    return Quests.find({"answer": {$ne:null}});
  },
  answer: function(){
    return this.answer;
  }
});

Template.patients.helpers({
  allFeelings:function(){
    return Quests.find({"feel": {$ne:null}});
  },
  feel: function(){
    return this.feel;
  }
});

Template.patients.helpers({
  allUsers: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  },
  id: function(){
    ret
  },
  firstName: function() {
    return this.profile.firstName;
  },
  lastName: function() {
    return this.profile.lastName;
  }
});


Template.patients.onRendered(function () {
  Session.set('show', false);
});

Template.patients.events({
  'change #hide': function (event) {
    Session.set('show', false);
  },
  'change #show': function (event) {
    Session.set('show', true);
  }
});

Template.patients.helpers({
  show: function() {
    return Session.get('show');
  },
});

Template.patients.topGenresChart = function() {
    return {
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
        text: 'Answers Progress'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'W1',
            'W2',
            'W3',
            'W4',
            'W5',
            'W6',
            'W7'
        ],
        plotBands: [{ // last week
            from: 5.5,
            to: 7,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Answers'
        },
        categories: [
            '0',
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5',
            '6'
        ],
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' points'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Question 1 Progress',
        data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 5, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Question 2 Progress',
        data: [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4]
    }]}
};
```

Now the problem is how to put in series.data the data taken from Quests.answer, considering that answer is an array of 10 number.
How to use the #each function to display the answer's data for one user at time: actually if I select show I'll see all the user's answers under every user.

Quests is like:

```
Schemas.Quests = new SimpleSchema
createdAt:
    type: Date
    autoValue: ->
        if this.isInsert
            new Date()
answer:
    type: [Number]
    optional:true

feel:
    type: Number
    optional:true

userId:
    type: String

patient: 
    type: String
    optional:true
```

feel could be a number: 0 1 2.
answer is an array of 10 item, numbers from 0 to 6.

EDITED:

Example of MongoDB elements:
- Meteor.users

```
createdAt: Tue Dec 05 2017 10:56:24 GMT+0100 
__proto__: Object
emails : Array(1)
      0 : {address: "denise@test.it", verified: false}
      length : 1
      __proto__ : Array(0)
profile :
      firstName : "Denise"
      lastName : "Blabla"
      __proto__ : Object
services :
      password: {bcrypt: "$2a$10$ddJ8F.k2uJ2lZaDfvMNEdObxdMXwAdxSSQRYtHRG6Juoh8HVtC8Ju"}
      resume : {loginTokens: Array(0)}
      __proto__ : Object
_id: "RTS2LR2jaBjidEiB7"
__proto__:Object
length : 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And this is an example of the Quests:

```
0 : 
  answer : (10) ["1", "5", "6", "5", "1", "5", "5", "6", "0", "2"]
  patient : "Denise Blabla"
  userId : "RTS2LR2jaBjidEiB7"
  _id : "7NwjGmGyz7zjbzBqC"
  __proto__ : Object
1 :
  feel : "0"
  patient : "Denise Blabla"
  userId : "RTS2LR2jaBjidEiB7"
  _id : "5KtDQof3o9gt8CYJg"
  __proto__ : Object
2 :
  answer : (10) ["0", "4", "4", "0", "4", "5", "0", "1", "3", "6"]
  patient : "Denise Blabla"
  userId : "RTS2LR2jaBjidEiB7"
  _id : "7t46pAihMBNWwmYpN"
  __proto__ : Object
```

What I want is to display something like this in a table:

```
Denise Blabla
  Week   ||  Q1  ||  Q2  ||  ...  ||  Q10  ||  Feel  
  Week 1 ||  6   ||  4   ||  ...  ||  1    ||   0
  Week 2 ||  3   ||  1   ||  ...  ||  5    ||   2

Anne Smith
  Week   ||  Q1  ||  Q2  ||  ...  ||  Q10  ||  Feel 
  Week 1 ||  5   ||  5   ||  ...  ||  1    ||   1
  Week 2 ||  3   ||  2   ||  ...  ||  3    ||   0
```

Comment: Pass user's id in helper, and then do corresponding `find`.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. You are trying to make a chart from the data, correct? That is one question. Then there's the use of `{{#each}}` in your template which is a completely separate question. Your `allAnswers` and `allFeelings` helpers need to filter based on the current patient being displayed.

Comment: It would also help to show an example `Quests` object since we can't tell how it relates to `users`

Comment: @MichelFloyd Yes, exactly!
I'd add an example of Quests...

Comment: Something's missing on `Quests` - there's no date or anything to sort them by. How do you know which `Week` a `Quest` document corresponds to? You can't depend on database order.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in meteor programming...can you suggest me the better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

First part of the question, showing the data from the related collection `Quests` in your template:

```
Template.patients.helpers({
  allAnswers() {
    return Quests.find({ userId: this._id, answer: { $exists: true }}).map((el) => el.answer);
  },
  allFeelings() {
    return Quests.find({ userId: this._id, feel: { $exists: true }}).map((el) => el.feel);
  }
});
```

This is basically doing an inline *join* on the related collection using `userId` as the matching key.

Your highchart will be done in a similar fashion:

```
Template.patients.topGenresChart = function() {
    return {
      ... chart parameters as you had them before

    series: [{
        name: 'Question 1 Progress',
        data: () => { Quests.find({ userId: this._id, answer: { $exists: true }}).map((el) => el.answer)}
    }, {
        name: 'Question 2 Progress',
        data: () => { Quests.find({ userId: this._id, feel: { $exists: true }}).map((el) => el.feel)}
    }]}
};
```

However:

1. In your question you say that `answer` is an *array of 10 numbers* but your schema has defines it as a `String`. Did you mean `[String]`
2. You say that `feel` is a number `0 1 2` but your template is iterating over it with `{{#each}}`.
3. It's not at all clear what you're trying to chart in your two series. Your example data has arrays of 7 elements each but what data from `Quests` is supposed to go in there?
4. You're referring to the same chart data: `chartObject=topGenresChart` twice from `{{> highchartsHelper ...}}` - that means you're going to display the exact same chart twice even though you're giving each a different ID. What is your intent there?

In any case the answer should give you enough to get going.

Note also that your `feel` and `answer` helpers are redundant. You could use `{{feel}}` and `{{answer}}` directly in your template without going through a helper since those helpers just return `this.feel` and `this.answer` respectively.

Comment: Ok I try to be more specific: I'm collecting questionnaire's answers, every week I'll collect 10 ansers in an array like: week 1, answer[1,2,3,4,2,,...] ,
 week 2, answer[0,2,3,4,5,...]; and every week I'll collect a number in "feel" like: week1 feel=1, week2 feel=0....
1. How can I better define "anser"?
2. I had use {{#each}} because I have more feel in a month
3. the seven items must be stored in anser as you can see in the expalination
4.I refer to highchart twice because I want to display a chart for feel and a chart for answer for every user
By the way, I've try and it doesn't work

Comment: 1. So each `Quest` document has a number array `answers` of length 10 and a single number `feel` correct? (I've fixed your schema to reflect that) 2. Does it then take 7 `Quest` documents to create a week's worth of `feel` data? Can you show what you're actually trying to achieve? i.e. this is what my data looks like in mongodb and this is how I want it to look on a page?

Comment: I've add and an example of what I want to display and of the mongodb...Then I'd like to have a highchart for the progress of the feel field and one for the progress of the column of the table, so for example how the value for Q1 change in 3 weeks.